# ContentNegotiationViewResolver secure with spring security authentication on every request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am willing to implement Spring Security along with ContentNegotiationViewResolver. I am having several webservices having endpoints like.

http://www.example.com/list.xml

http://www.example.com/list.json

I want my request XML like this.

```
<request>
    <login>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin</password>
    </login>
    <internalrequest>
      <otherparam1></otherparam1>
      <otherparam2></otherparam2>
    </internalrequest>
</request>
```

I am well aware of DigestAuthentication and BasicAuthentication using Spring Security, but I want to implement `the login credentials should be checked on every request and they should be the internal part of every request object` like the way I have presented the request object, and then only the other data will be processed to the user.

Can you please suggest me how can I proceed and what strategy should I implement this kind of security.